# Count consecutive true elements in boolean array

Tags: java

I have a boolean array such as the following below.

```
[true, false, false, true, true, false]
```

I'd like to convert it to the code fragment below, essentially to count the number of true statements that are present.

```
[1,2]
```

the one represents the first true and the two represent the two true statements that are together. I'm unsure of how to go about this.

Comment: _unsure how to go about this_ - Writing a for loop seems like a good start...

Comment: start with a loop, check the value, make a count, then show us and we'll see

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean[] input = {true, false, false, true, true, false};
    
    int count = 0;
    
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i]) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > 0) {
                output.add(count);
            }
            count = 0;
        }
        
        if (i == input.length - 1 && count > 0) {
            output.add(count);
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two nested loops should do the trick: the outer loop finds the first `true` element and the inner loop counts consecutive elements:

```java
int[] countTrues(boolean[] input) {
  final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
  int i = 0;
  while (i < input.length) {
    if (input[i]) {
      int count = 0;
      while (i < input.length && input[i]) {
        ++count;
        ++i;
      }
      result.add(count);
    }
    ++i;
  }
  return result.stream().mapToInt(x->x).toArray();
}
```

I am lazy and using an ArrayList of boxed integers. For simple inputs of a few elements that shouldn't be a problem (and I assume this method will not be called on a hot path). There are other solutions too. Your array will have at most `input.length` elements. You can keep track of how many `true` sequences you have already counted and populate the result array, and in the end copy the sub-array which has values in it. Or you can count the number of transitions from false to true and use that as your result array size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  A list makes it easier.

- if the current value is false, an end of sequence is possible.
- so check if count > 0, if so, add count to list.  Reset count to 0.
- if the current value is true, increment count.
- finally - special case - if `i` is last value and true, add current count to list.

```
boolean [] bools = {false, true, false, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, false, true};

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < bools.length; i++) {
    if (!bools[i]) {
        if (count > 0) {
            list.add(count);
            count = 0;
        }
    } else { 
        count++;
    }
}
if (bools[bools.length-1]) {
    list.add(count);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 4, 1]
```

Note. if you really want an `int[] array` just do the following:

```
int[] arr = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```